# Discord.py Warning "discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds." while using AsyncIOScheduler

Tags: discord.py, apscheduler

I used Discord.py to create discord bot and run it all day. This bot performs crawling of community sites once every 10 seconds. After about 3 hours of execution, the warning message was displayed every 10 seconds.

My bot code:

```
import os
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

token = "token"

url = "site url"
params = {
    'id': 'id',}
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent}

async def read_site():
    resp = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

    article_nums = soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr", class_="ub-content us-post")
    with open("recent.txt", "r") as f:
        recent = int(f.read())

    new_flag = False
    for val in article_nums:
        article_num = val.select_one("td", class_='num').get_text()
        if not article_num.isdecimal():
            continue
        article_num = int(article_num)
        
        if article_num > recent:
            new_flag = True
            recent = article_num

    if new_flag:
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send(recent)
        
    with open("recent.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(recent))
    f.close()
    ...

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(read_site, 'interval', seconds=3, misfire_grace_time=5)
    scheduler.start()

    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

client.run(token)
```

If anyone knows about this error, I would appreciate your help.

I saw a similar article in stackoverflow, so I set

```
misfire_grace_time
```

in the

```
add_job
```

function, but I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds" can be caused by the blocking in your code. Then if the execution of this part of blocking code takes longer time then discord gateway will show this warning. 
From the code provided, the line of `requests.get(...)` is definitely a blocking line of code since `requests` library is all synchronous. Consider changing this part of the code to `aiohttp`.
Also, there might be other libraries that could be blocking. Replace them with similar asynchronous libraries.